# ACF gives empty string for some

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am having an issue that is driving me crazy. 
My problem is as follows, some input (about opening hours) is entered in my wordpress backend (via ACF fields plugin). 
It looks like this (note that everything is filled in):

[image: problem 1]

My code is nothing special, just as you would call any ACF field, so as follows:

```
echo "Ma: "; echo the_field('maandag'); echo "<br />";
echo "Di: "; echo the_field('dinsdag'); echo "<br />";
echo "Woe: "; echo the_field('woensdag'); echo "<br />";
echo "Don: "; echo the_field('donderdag'); echo "<br />";
echo "Vr: "; echo the_field('vrijdag'); echo "<br />";
echo "Zat: "; echo the_field('zaterdag'); echo "<br />";
echo "Zon: "; echo the_field('zondag'); echo "<br />";
echo the_field('speciale'); 
echo the_field('vakantie');
```

On my webpage it looks like this:

[image: problem 2]

I am literally baffled as to why it only shows some of the fields and others not.

Note that at first it did show all the different days (monday to sunday), but it did NOT show my 2 textarea's. So I did some googling and some results told me that a maximum number of vars might have been reached, so I deleted wednesday and thursday to check if my textareas would work. This obviously did not work, as soon as i readded wednesday and thursday, those did not work anymore either.
What I noticed is that when I completely delete the new post type in my wordpress back end (permanently delete it, it would still show me values).
I have no clue what is going on!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try to use the field key instead of the field name. You'll get the field key when you edit the field's definitions with ACF and tick "field key" in the white options pane at the very top (right) of the screen.

Comment: I don't think that's the cause (I'd check again your field names for misspellings) but notice that [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) function already echoes the field value, so you should remove all _echoes_ before this function. Or you could use [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead. Like this: `echo "Ma: " . get_field('maandag') . "<br />";`